# Cassandra 1.2.3 heap grows as the number of rows grows

Tags: java, cassandra, heap-memory

Running Cassandra 1.2.3 with 10GB RAM leads to ever increasing heap usage as the number of keys grows. It's now about 8.3G and the nodes experience heap pressure that leads to timeouts.

cfstats output:

```
Keyspace: profiles
    Read Count: 33775531
    Read Latency: 11.160335890411316 ms.
    Write Count: 146030154
    Write Latency: 0.03436538754180866 ms.
    Pending Tasks: 0
        Column Family: profiles
        SSTable count: 12
        Space used (live): 161353987766
        Space used (total): 161604490499
        Number of Keys (estimate): 162628352
        Memtable Columns Count: 69256
        Memtable Data Size: 58138189
        Memtable Switch Count: 6844
        Read Count: 33775532
        Read Latency: 13.964 ms.
        Write Count: 146030157
        Write Latency: 0.032 ms.
        Pending Tasks: 0
        Bloom Filter False Positives: 2498002
        Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0.31157
        Bloom Filter Space Used: 110145928
        Compacted row minimum size: 30
        Compacted row maximum size: 73457
        Compacted row mean size: 3508
```

Here's the heap dump.

Analyzing it did not lead to anything but the hypothesis that there's a memory leak since I see a lot of almost empty arrays and maps.

I'd appreciate ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're caching data, but you're not using JNA (Java Native Access).  JNA allows Cassandra to store O(n) data structures (those that grow with data set size) off heap, including the caches.  [This document](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/install_jre) describes how to set up JNA.  Your cache settings are configured per table/CF when you define your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Does the heap drops after the explicit gc is called?

Comment: This is not an answer. Choose wisely what is appropriate as answer and what is more appropriate as comment.

Comment: To arrive at the answer one had to understand the problem more, the original author mentioned that the heap grows as the rows are added. It seems obvious to me as the memtable would too grow but as the memtable flushes to the sstable the heap should be reclaimed. The GC will reclaim it. There is a possibility that the heap is there but not getting gced and it might get reclaimed. If the heap stays up for longer duration then it should be concern else not. Prateek, you should not discourage people from not asking questions for getting right answer. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: `Prateek, you should not discourage people from not asking questions for getting right answer.` I am not discouraging you to ask questions but pointing out that asking questions should be done in comments. This is exactly the reason we have comments option in SO. When you want to get clarification about a question you should add a comment and ask for clarification and OP would edit his post to make it more understandable.